# How to convert 2 horizontal panes to vertical panes in tmux?

Tags: tmux

After doing join-pane on 2 windows, you have 2 horizontal panes. How do I rearrange the panes to be vertical panes instead?

Answer (score 463, accepted):

`C-b space` (bound to `next-layout` by default) cycles through available layouts, you can also use the `select-layout` command.

```
M-1 to M-5  Arrange panes in one of the five preset layouts: even-
            horizontal, even-vertical, main-horizontal, main-
            vertical, or tiled.
```

On OS X, `M` is `Esc`, i.e. `Ctrl-b` `Esc-1`.

See `man tmux` for more details.

Comment: Yup, that worked, `C-b M-1` worked for me

Comment: On Linux, Meta => Alt key, so Ctrl-b + Alt-<1-5> does the work.

Comment: If all of above is not working for you, try C-b <Space>

Comment: `C-b <Space>` is the only thing that worked for me indeed

Answer (score 18):

In Mac OS Yosemite, this  works:

`Prefix + Option-[1-5]`

e.g: Ctrl-b Option-1

Comment: on my mac with iTerm2, this translates to `Control-b ESC 1`

Answer (score 14):

You *should* be able to use:

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>b</kbd> <kbd>meta</kbd>-<kbd>2</kbd>

to do this, but I'm unable to test it since OS X doesn't like anything too "meta" (we have at least that in common).

Source: http://hyperpolyglot.org/multiplexers

Comment: You should be able to configure your terminal emulator with “option as meta“ (*Terminal*) or “option as +Esc“ (*iTerm2*), but you can always type C-b M-2 manually as C-b ESC 2.

Answer (score 2):

There are also an options for explicitly requiring the join/split to happen vertically/horizontally: `-h` and `-v`

(see man page and note that the `-h`/`-v` do **not** refer to the direction of the separator line).

Comment: how does tmux swap two pane?

Comment: With the `swap-pane` command.

Comment: or use  C-b space