# How to automatically balance tmux panes whenever a pane is added/removed?

Tags: tmux

To balance panes in the current window, one can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>b</kbd> <kbd>Meta</kbd>-<kbd>1</kbd>..<kbd>5</kbd> ([1](https://superuser.com/questions/456775/how-to-auto-resize-panes-in-tmux), [2](https://superuser.com/questions/493048/how-to-convert-2-horizontal-panes-to-vertical-panes-in-tmux)). However, is there a way to perform such balancing **automatically** whenever a pane is added or removed?

For example, consider that I have two equally high panes in the `even-vertical` layout. Now, when I split the current pane into two (top and bottom), I would like tmux to automatically balance all the panes so I got three equally high panes in the `even-vertical` layout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can provide your own bindings consisting of commands joined by `\;`. For example in your `~/.tmux.conf` add

```
bind-key '"' split-window \; select-layout -n \; select-layout -p
```

This makes <kbd>Ctrl-b "</kbd> split the window, then change the layout to the next layout, then back to the previous layout.  You would need to do this for other commands that add or remove windows.

---

If you want more automatic control, you can write a background tmux control mode process to listen to a real tmux process. It gets notifications of everything happening in the real tmux, and you could then send `select-layout` commands whenever you see a notification of a new window, or a deleted window.  I've not experimented much with this, but if you use 2 terminals and run a normal session in one

```
tmux new -s mysession
```

and in the other

```
tmux -C attach -t mysession
```

then when you split windows, add new ones, or close them in the normal tmux you will get lines like

```
%layout-change @2 91a8,80x23,0,0[80x11,0,0,5,80x11,0,12,7]
%window-add @3
%window-close @1
```

in the control tmux. When you see these you can write `select-layout -n` in the control mode, and it affects the first. There's a [python library](https://github.com/tony/libtmux) to use this mechanism, which I have not looked at further.

Comment: But what if the current layout is different from `even-vertical`? I would like to keep the layout that is currently being used.

Comment: Finding the current layout is difficult. You can instead cycle forwards, then backwards. I updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks. I thought that there had be a better way than rebinding all the keys, though. For example, I regularly kill a pane just by exiting the shell, which is pretty impossible to "rebind" in tmux.

Comment: I've added a possible mechanism that may interest you, the control mode of tmux. I've not used it but it looks feasible, if a bit of an overkill.